# how to Split And Count cell at Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, split

i have a table like this

```
Food           |
---------------|
nasi           | 
nasi goreng    |
nasi uduk      |
nasi,ikan,lalap|
nasi           |
```

i want result count nasi = 3, nasi goreng = 1 nasi uduk = 1

how to Split And Count cell at Sql Server ?

Comment: it is very bad db design to store values as csv

Comment: @numus175, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Eduard Uta i have no idea, just search in google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a string split function and `CROSS APPLY`

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
    Food varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES
('nasi'),
('nasi goreng'),
('nasi uduk'),
('nasi,ikan,lalap'),
('nasi')

SELECT ca.Value AS Food,
      count(*) AS Count 
FROM @SampleData sd
CROSS APPLY
(
    Select * from [dbo].[SplitString](sd.Food,',')
) ca
GROUP BY ca.Value
```

String split function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString] (@Text varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
   Select Pos = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
        ,Value = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
   From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@Text,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
   Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
```

Returns

```
Food          Count
---------------------
ikan          1
lalap         1
nasi          3
nasi goreng   1
nasi uduk     1
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
Select food_Name,COUNT(*) from (
 SELECT 
  Tbl.Col.value('./text()[1]','varchar(50)')as food_Name
FROM 
(Select cast('<a>'+ replace((SELECT food As [*] FOR XML PATH('')), ',', '</a><a>') + '</a>' as xml)as t 
 from Your_Table) tl
Cross apply 
tl.t.nodes('/a') AS Tbl(Col))t2
group by food_Name
```